# Chidambara Mahatmyam is part of Skanda Purana or Sthala Purana?

Tags: shiva, skanda-purana

Please let me know if Chidambara Mahatmyam comes under Skanda Purana then which khanda it is available and chapter numbers also.  I came to know there are 26 chapters available. Is there any where Sanskrit or Telugu script available for the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to Shastri, P. (1995) Introduction to the Puranas, New Delhi: Rashtriya Sanskrit Sansthan, pp.118–20, the Skanda Purana grouped into seven khaṇḍas (total of 26 chapters), each named after a major pilgrimage region and are called Mahatmyas. This does not include Chidambaram. The primary Siva kshetras included are Kedarnath, Arunachala and Varanasi.

The complete Skanda purana is available [in Sanskrit](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303192901/http://is1.mum.edu/vedicreserve/skanda.htm).

Chidambara mahatmyam by E. A. Sivaraman, 1993, Bharatiya Vidya Bhavan edition, mentions that the mahatmyam is from Tamil.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 26 chapters what I mentioned is belong to Chidambara Mahatmyam only in Skanda Purana. I want to know in which Khanda it is available.

Comment: There is no Chidambara Mahatmyam in the Skanda Purana. I have provided you the link to Skanda Purana.

Comment: Yeah of course in that link don't find.. Do you know anywhere it is available apart from Skanda Purana?

Comment: As given above, the translation is provided by Sivaraman and available from Bharatiya Vidya Bhavan. The tamil original is written by Annaswamy Iyer in poetical form and available locally in Chidambaram.