# Is Rig Vedic Indra only Sri Rama?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, rama, rig-veda, indra

According to Rig Veda (and other Vedas) Indra is the all pervading and supreme being:

> In every figure he [Indra] hath been the mode... Indra assumes many form by his Maya (6.47.18)
>
> He who is Lord of all the world that moves and breathes (1.101.5)
>
> Indra surpasses heaven and earth; a mere portion of him is equal to both earth and heaven. (6.30.1)

There are many other such verses. Rig Ved also says:

> **इन्द्र॒: सीतां॒ नि गृ॑ह्णातु॒** तां पू॒षानु॑ यच्छतु । May Indra **marry Sītā** (4.57.7)
>
> **यद्ध॒ त्यं मा॒यिनं॑ मृ॒गं** तमु॒ त्वं मा॒यया॑वधी॒रर्च॒न्ननु॑ स्व॒राज्य॑म् ॥ You [Indra] with craft have slain that **deceptive deer**, manifesting your own sovereignty.”

Now the only other reference to marrying Sita and slaying a deceptive deer is for Sri Raam:

> **Disguised in the form of a deer** studded with precious stones, a terrific demon by name, Maricha, a follower of Ravana, allured **Sita**........ Rama wielding a bow in his arm, **chased that deer and killed that running one**, with an arrow of curved knots. (Valmiki Ramayan 6.126.22-24)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is Indra mentioned as anybody else or only Shri Raam?

Comment: Sītā means *furrow* in Sanskrit. 
Also the translation of 4.57.7 which you gave, is incorrect.  This is a better one
*Let Indra lay down the Furrow; let Pūṣan extend her straight.
Let her, full of milk, yield milk to us, summer after summer*

Comment: So, it was more of a misinterpretation or mistranslation which made you have such a view of there being Rāma and Sītā. Perhaps you may not know how Sītā got her name in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa. She got her name because she was found in a *furrow* when her foster father Janaka was ritually plowing the sacred fields. That is why  she was named Sītā (furrow)

Comment: If you are interested, in where I have taken this translation from, it is by *Jamison & Brereton* https://archive.org/details/the-rigveda-the-earliest-poetry-of-india-all-3-volume-sets/  . So, this translation is much better and latest scholarly translation, far more accurate and researched than R.T.H Griffith, H.H. Wilson and Muller. These three old translations are outdated, archaic, pretty unreadable and have lots of inaccuracies.

Answer (score 0):

The R.V. 1.80.7 verse, about Mayin Mriga is Vrittra our inner Negative Thoughts (Vrittis) that originates from our Mind (Manas), which Indra slayed with his Vajra (Knowledge/Buddhi) as I have discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56891/20968) of mine. One can also check [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57085/20968) of mine for more regarding this topic.

And, as for the RV 4.57.7 verse, this is an agricultural verse.

RV 4.57.6-7.:

> 6. Auspicious Sita, come thou near: we venerate and worship thee That thou mayst bless and prosper us and bring us fruits abundantly.
> 7. May Indra press (गृह्णातु) the furrow down, may Pusan guide its course aright. May she, as rich in milk, be drained for us through each succeeding year.

Hindi Translation.:

> हे श्रेष्ठ ऐश्वर्य प्रदान करने वाली सीतै ! आप हमारे ऊपर अनुकम्पा करने वाली हों । हम आपकी वन्दना करते हैं, जिससे आप हमें श्रेष्ठ ऐश्वर्य प्रदान करें तथा श्रेष्ठ फल प्रदान करें ॥६॥
>
> O Sita, bestower of the best prosperity!  You are kind to us.  We worship You, so that You may grant us the best prosperity and the best fruits. ॥6॥
>
> इन्द्रदेव हल की मूठ सँभालें । पूषादेव उसकी देख-भाल करें, तब धरती श्रेष्ठ धान्य तथा जल से परिपूर्ण होकर हमारे लिए धान्य आदि का दोहन करे ॥७॥
>
> May Lord Indra handle the handle of the plough.  May Pushadev (Sun) takes care of it, then the earth will be filled with the best grains and water and will harvest the grains etc. for us.॥7॥

So, it's basically talking about Indra (Sky/Cloud) to rain the Earth/Furrow (Sita) down and Pushan (Sun) to nourish it for good harvest (prosperity/fruit).

Again, the word gṛhṇātu (गृह्णातु) can also be translated as Marry. So, if i take your translation.

> May Indra marry Sītā.

This is also true.

As, Indra being Sky/Heaven.

A.V. 15.10.:

> 10-11 Great power comes to him and he becomes endowed with great power. Who knows that Āditya is Royalty (Kshatriya) and that Heaven is Indra.

And Sita is Earth/Cow.

Y.V. 12.70.:

> 70. Approved by Visvedevas and by Maruts, balmed be the furrow with sweet-flavoured fatness. Succulent, teeming with thy milky treasure, turn hitherward to us with milk, O Furrow (Sita).

And, Heaven and Earth are said to be Husband and Wife.

R.V. 1.164.33.:

> 33. Dyaus (Heaven) is my Father, my begetter: kinship is here. This great earth is my kin and Mother. Between the wide-spread world-halves is the birthb-place: the Father laid the Daughter's germ within it.

Now, as, I have already mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54129/20968) of mine, how Earth = Rig Veda, Atmosphere = Yajur Veda and Heaven = Sama Veda. Plus, [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50019/20968) also mentions, how Rig Veda (Earth) divided itself into three forms and married Sama Veda (Heaven).

And, [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57103/20968) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53751/20968), i have also mentioned how Indra is a self realised Jivatma who after knowing Paramatma (Maheshwara) becomes Ishana/Ruler/Ishwara himself.

And, this [Jiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51794/20968) and [Indra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54112/20968) are nothing but Bhagawan Maheshwara only.

So, Basically, Rig Veda (Earth/Sita) is Prakriti and has Purusha (Dyaus/Sky/Heaven/Indra) as her husband. Again, the Prakriti (Rik) is divided into 3 gunas raj, sat, tam. So, the only one single Prakriti takes 3 forms for marrying Purusha.

Shandilya Upanishad 3:01.:

> “Maheshvara (the Great Lord Shiva) who is black and yellow (Krishna-Pinglam) rules with Avidya, Mula-Prakriti (Uma) or Maya that is red (Rajas/Mahalakshmi), white (Sattva/Mahasaraswati) and black (Tamas/Mahakali) and that is co-existent with him”.

Conclusion.: The above verse is not related to Itihasa Ramayana but is an agricultural verse and Heaven (Indra) and Earth (Sita) are said to be Husband and Wife in Rig Veda.

Note.: Sometimes, Indra is said to be the Son of the Heaven just as Sita is said to be the daughter of the Earth.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..