# Is Indra, Shiva?

Tags: shiva, gods, indra

I was wondering how this evolved during times.

How Indra disappeared instead of Rudra, or Shiva ...or even Vishnu?

Is Shiva , Indra and vice-versa?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Vaidik Lord Indra is indeed Bhagawan Rudra only.

The Sri Rudram of Yajur-Veda denotes Lord Shiva as Indra and Yama as following.:

> *“namo yaamyaya cha **kshemyaya cha** |”*
>
> *Salutations to him to him who punishes in hell and **to him who grants favours in heaven.** – (YajurVeda 4:5:6.1.6).*

Not only this but also there are many references to conclude that Vedic Indra is indeed Shiva.

> *“sá yád dákṣiṇāṃ díśam ánu vyácalad **índro** bhūtvā́nuvyàcalad bálam annādáṃ kr̥tvā́ |” (Atharva Veda XV: 14:2).*
>
> *“Shiva (Vratya), when he went away to the southern region, went away having become **Indra**, and having made Strength an eater of food”.*

This clearly says that Lord Shiva (who is called Vratya) becomes Indra. There are many references to conclude that Vedic Indra is indeed Shiva.

Regarding it, Shatpath Brahman also reveal the same fact.

> *“tamabravīd**aśani**rasīti | tadyadasya tannāmākarod**vidyut**tadrūpamabhavadvidyudvā
> aśanistasmādyaṃ vidyuddhantyaśanirabadhīdityāhuḥ so ‘bravījjyāyānvā ato ‘smi
> dhehyeva me nāmeti |” (Shatapatha Brahmana 6:1:3:14).*
>
> *“He said to him, **‘Thou art Asani.’** And because he gave him that name, the lightning became suchlike, for Asani is the **lightning**: hence they say of him whom the lightning strikes, ‘Asani has smitten him.’ He said, ‘Surely, I am mightier than that: give me yet a name!’”*

This Asani is none other then Lord Shiva as confirmed by Kaushitaki Brahmana.

> *“sa.vai.tvam.ity.abravīd.aśanir.eva.iti yad.**aśanir.indras**.tena |” (Kaushitaki Brahmana 6:3:41).*
>
> *“Prajapathi said to Rudra ‘Thou art Asani’ ; for **Asani is Indra**”.*

This is clear to Understand that again it is Lord Trayambak who is called Indra in the Vedas.

Hymn from Atharva Veda called as “Hymn to ‘Bhava’ and ‘Sarva’” eulogizes lord Shiva in his two aspects (names) viz. Bhava and Sarva. If we understand these names with reference to Sri Rudram hymn from Yajurveda, then it would become clear to us that Rudra is called ‘Bhava’ because he is the source of all and everything which exists (bhavati); and Rudra is called as ‘Sarva’ because he destroys everything from creatures to gods to galaxies to entire universe at the end of time. Hence, he is called the one who destroys everything (sarvam) hence the name ‘Sarva’.

> *“Namo **bhavaya** cha rudraya cha | namah **sharvaya** cha pashupataye cha |” (Yajurveda Sri Rudram- Anuvaka 5).*
>
> *“Salutations to Rudra who is **the source of all things (Bhava)** and to Him who is the destroyer of all ills (Rudra). Salutations to **the destroyer of everything (Sharva)** and to the protector of all beings in bondage (Pashupati)”.*

Atharva Veda’s hymn to Bhava and Sarva depicts Rudra’s these two names as two aspects and praises him with a song. But essentially Rudra is truly one. That hymn calls Rudra (Bhava / Sarva) as the slayer of demon “Vritra” as follows:

> *“**sahasrākṣáu vr̥trahánā huveháṃ dūrégavyūtī stuvánn emy ugráu** |
> yā́v asyéśathe dvipádo yáu cátuṣpadas táu no muñcatam áṃhasaḥ |” (Atharva Veda IV: 28:3).*
>
> ***“The thousand-eyed slayers of Vritra both do I invoke.** I go praising the two strong gods (ugrau) whose pastures extend far. Ye who rule all these two-footed and four-footed creatures, deliver us from grief and trouble”.*

Not only Rudra is called slayer of Vrita, but the Same Rudra is called wielder of thunder-bolt which is weapon of Indra.

> *“**śreṣṭho jātasya rudra śriyāsi tavastamastavasāṃ vajrabāho** |
> parṣi ṇaḥ pāramaṃhasaḥ svasti viśvā abhītī rapaso yuyodhi |” (Rig Veda 2.33.3).*
>
> ” ***In glory thou art the most glorious of all that exists, O Rudra, the strongest of the strong, thou wielder of the thunderbolt!** Carry us happily to the other shore of our anguish, and ward off all assaults of mischief”.*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..