# Among Puranas, is it only Vishnu-oriented Puranas that denigrate Indra?

Tags: indra

After being lauded as supreme in rig Veda, Indra is often depicted as a dependent deity in Vishnu-oriented Puranas, turning to Vishnu to save his status, that has been turned into a post that could have different occupants over time.

Do other Puranas denigrate Indra also?

Comment: Refer: [Is Rig Vedic Indra only Sri Rama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52531/is-rig-vedic-indra-only-sri-rama)

Comment: The flexibility of Sanskrit allows P N Oak-ish etymologies for anything (Taj Mahal = Tejomayalaya, The Satarudriyam does't praise Siva and so forth). @adiyarkku